# Hangman Game IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, ascii, python-2.x, ascii-art

Im trying to follow a tutorial to write a simple "Hangman style game", It runs ok, if you guess the letter correctly however, on your 1st incorrect guess the programme displays the 2nd ASCII graphic and not the 1st. when you guess your 2nd incorrect letter the 3rd graphic comes up but it is "distorted" like this:

Sorry, z isn't what we're looking for.

```
        +---------+
        |         |
        |         O
        |        -|-
        |        /             |
    ================
```

finally you make a 3rd incorrect guess and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./HangMan.py", line 118, in <module>
start()
File "./HangMan.py", line 44, in start
while game():
File "./HangMan.py", line 79, in game
hangedman(letters_wrong)
File "./HangMan.py", line 39, in hangedman
print graphic[hangman]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

- any advice would be appreciated.
- Sorry theres no comments on my code I'm VERY new to this..

Heres my code:

```
from random import *


player_score = 0

computer_score = 0

def hangedman(hangman):
    graphic = [
"""
        +---------+
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
    ================
""",
"""
        +---------+
        |         |
        |         O
        |
        |
        |
    ================
""",
"""
        +---------+
        |         |
        |         O
        |        -|-
        |        / \
        |
    ================
"""]

print graphic[hangman]
return

def start():
    print "Lets play a game of Hangman"
    while game():
        pass
     scores()

def game():
dictionary = ["box","ted","sad","bad"]
word = choice(dictionary)
word_length = len(word)
clue = word_length * ["_"]
tries = 3
letters_tried = ""
guesses = 0
letters_right = 0
letters_wrong = 0
global computer_score, player_score

while (letters_wrong != tries) and ("".join(clue) != word):
    letter = guess_letter()
    if len(letter)==1 and letter.isalpha():
        if letters_tried.find(letter) !=-1:
            print "you've already picked", letter
        else:
            letters_tried = letters_tried = letter
            first_index = word.find(letter)
            if first_index == -1:
                letters_wrong +=1
                print "Sorry,",letter,"isn't what we're looking for."
            else:
                print "Congratulations,",letter,"is correct."
                for i in range(word_length):
                    if letter == word[i]:
                        clue[i] = letter
    else:
        print "Choose another"

    hangedman(letters_wrong)
    print " ".join(clue)
    print "Guesses: ", letters_tried

    if letters_wrong == tries:
        print "Game Over"
        print "The word was",word
        computer_score += 1
        break
    if "".join(clue) == word:
        print "you win!"
        print "the word was", word
        player_score += 1
        break
return play_again()


def guess_letter():
    print
    letter = raw_input("Take a Guess at our mystery word:")
    letter.strip()
    letter.lower()
    print
    return letter

def play_again():
    answer = raw_input("Would you like to play again? y/n: ")
    if answer in ("y"):
        return answer
    else:
        print "Thank you see you next time"

def scores():
    global player_score, computer_score
    print "Hight Scores"
    print "Player: ", player_score
    print "Computer: ", computer_score

if __name__ == '__main__':
     start()
```

Comment: Lists are 0-based. So your list `graphic` has three entries with indexes 0, 1 and 2. Now you try to access `graphic[3]` and ... BOOM!

Comment: @Matthias Hi thanks for your comment, are you saying if I change the "tries = 3" to "tries = 2" it should work? If so I have tried that and I just get two guesses and it says game over...

Comment: I didn't check all of your code (which still has some logical errors like `letter.lower()` where you don't use the return value). I think you need a fourth image in the list.

Comment: I think the solution would be to have four elements in graphic. Let's add another element where the guy's head, neck and body is shown without the legs.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad Thanks for your help! adding a 4th graphic helped. now if you guess incorrectly on your 1st try it comes up with the 2nd graphic in the list and if you guess correctly on your 1st guess it displays the 1st graphic? I have made one Syntax error correction, in the while loop the 1st else condition used to read "letters_tried = letters_tried = letter" and now reads "letters_tried = letters_tried + letter". This has had no effect on the game as far as I can tell.... I think the problem is that an incorrect 1st guess calls the graphic indexed 1 and not 0....any thoughts?

Comment: I am certainly not a Python expert. In most other languages I would have already written an answer, but in the case of Python I would not dare to do it unless we clearly see a solution. letters_wrong is passed to hangedman. letters_wrong is initialized with 0 and incremented whenever a wrong letter is chosen. It makes sense to have four graphics, since you have an empty one while no mistakes were made and you actually need four graphics. However, it seems that even after the fix something is not right. I think I could help if you would edit your question with the newest version of your

Comment: code and some information about what was the input and output step-by-step.